# Can't Find WeatherKit Historical Data and Trouble with Attribution

Tags: ios, swiftui, weatherkit

I would like to add some historical weather data to an app. I am able to use the new
WeatherKit to get current weather but cannot find ANY information to tell me how to
access historical data. One of the WWDC videos made reference to adding a start and end
date to the WeatherService call but I cannot find any info on this.

Also, I am struggling with the attribution requirements. I can make it work but only in
light mode. When the device is in dark mode, the Apple Weather Logo is just a white
box in the dark background (I assume the logo is there but in white - but can't prove it).

[image]

[image]

This is a simplified version - fetching current weather only:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    @State private var weather: Weather?
    @State private var attLogo: URL?
    @State private var attributionURL: URL?
    @State private var logoImage: Image?

    let weatherService = WeatherService.shared

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let weather {
                VStack {
                    Text("San Francisco")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                    Text("\(weather.currentWeather.temperature.formatted()) | \(weather.currentWeather.condition.description)")
                }
            }//if let
            Spacer()
        
            //white letters on white box if device in dark mode
            AsyncImage(url: attLogo)
        
            Group{
                if let attributionURL {
                    Link("Weather Attribution", destination: attributionURL)
                }
            }//att group
        }//outer v
        .padding()
        .task {
            do {
                let location = CLLocation(latitude: 37.77, longitude: -122.41)
                self.weather = try await weatherService.weather(for: location)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }//do catch
        }//task 1
        .task {
            do {
                let attribution = try await weatherService.attribution
                let attributionLink = attribution.legalPageURL
                self.attributionURL = attributionLink
                let attributionLogo = colorScheme == .light ? attribution.combinedMarkDarkURL : attribution.combinedMarkLightURL
                self.attLogo = attributionLogo              
            } catch {
                print("failed to load attribution")
            }
        }//task for logo and link
    }//body
}//struct
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 14.0 Beta, iOS 16.0 (20A5283p) in Simulator

Comment: These should probably be two separate questions. Your second issue may be because you’re trying to store a reference to a view — the image should be generated dynamically, in the hierarchy

Comment: Consider that it’s the first beta version.

Comment: The logo isn't there [combined-mark-light.png](https://weather-data.apple.com/assets/branding/combined-mark-light.png) & [combined-mark-dark.png](https://weather-data.apple.com/assets/branding/combined-mark-dark.png)

Comment: Agreed. There is no hurry, so I'll standby. For others, one could certainly capture the black on white and reverse the colors with an image editing software.

Comment: In the code above, the colorScheme check returns the DarkURL when in .light. This is reversed ... though faithful to Apple's Meet Weather Kit from WWDC 2022.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 10 July both logo marks are unavailable at the provided links. I have created a `placeholder` in the `AsyncImage` for now, I don't know if it would ever pass Apple's check but it seems viable for a Beta/offline solution.

```
if let arributionLogo = arributionLogo{
    AsyncImage(url: arributionLogo) { image in
        image.scaledToFit()
    } placeholder: {
        Label("Apple Weather", systemImage: "cloud.sun.fill")
    }
}else{
    ProgressView()
}
if let arributionLink = arributionLink{
    Link("Other data sources", destination: arributionLink)
}else{
    ProgressView()
}
```

Historical Weather is now available with

```
let forecast = try await weatherService.weather(for: location, including:.hourly(startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate))
```

And

```
let forecast = try await weatherService.weather(for: location, including: .daily(startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate))
```

Comment: Any idea how to obtain historic weather via the REST API?

Comment: @MrWillihog I haven't tried but maybe if you add them to the query. In standard Apple format.

Comment: That's good news on the historical data. There must be some other changes with Beta 3 - at first attempt, even the stuff that DID work before is no longer working for me. I'll do some searching.

Comment: @JohnSF yes a lot is broken right now I went back to Beta 2 because I was getting an error that has already been reported and MinuteWeather isn't decoding.

Comment: @JohnSF the images seems to be fixed now.

Comment: Agreed - works for me. Now hopefully the Weather API will be fixed next.

Comment: With Xcode Version 14.0 beta 4 (14A5284g) and iOS 16 I am able to retrieve historical data just as lorem ipsum states. At first attempt, it did not work on the simulator, but definitely does on a device. (yes, I am signed into iCloud on the simulator)

Comment: Correction to my comment yesterday. The attempt to add historical start and end dates has no effect. Using the daily option, what I get is a ten day forecast starting today, regardless of the dates used.

Comment: Thank you for the code @lorem ipsum! A nit for others: the image resulting from the URL will have to be .resizable() before .scaledToFit().

Comment: In another forum, an Apple Frameworks Engineer wrote, "This is a known issue (historical data fetch) that will be addressed soon." The post is from 1 week ago.

Comment: Was this ever fixed? I still am getting only 10 days of forecast when using start/stop times when using the .daily fetch @SwiftAero

Comment: Nevermind, my iPhone was still on iOS 16.0, updating resolved the issue