# WeatherKit error in displaying attribution information

Tags: swiftui, weatherkit

I have the weatherKit Service working. I need to display Apple logo.
Edited code as suggested

```
struct WView: View {

@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

@State private var weather: Weather?
@State private var attributionLogo: URL?
@State private var attributionURL: URL?
@State private var logoImage: Image?

let weatherService = WeatherService.shared

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if let weather {
            VStack {
                Text("San Francisco")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                Text("\(weather.currentWeather.temperature.formatted()) | \(weather.currentWeather.condition.description)")
            }
        }//if let
        Spacer()
        Group {
            if let logo = self.attributionLogo{
                AsyncImage(url: logo) { image in
                    image
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(height: 20)
                } placeholder: {
                    Label("Apple Weather", systemImage: "cloud.sun.fill")
                }
            }else{
                ProgressView()
            }
            if let url = self.attributionURL{
                Link("Other data sources", destination: url)
            }else{
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
    }//outer v
    .padding()
    .task {
        do {
            let location = CLLocation(latitude: 37.77, longitude: -122.41)
            self.weather = try await weatherService.weather(for: location)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }//do catch
    }//task 1
    .task {
        do {
            let attribution = try await weatherService.attribution
            let attributionLink = attribution.legalPageURL
            self.attributionURL = attributionLink
            self.attributionLogo = colorScheme == .light ? attribution.combinedMarkDarkURL : attribution.combinedMarkLightURL
        } catch {
            print("failed to load attribution")
        }
    }//task for logo and link
}//body
```

}//struct

Edit:
AsyncImage returns this image as seen in debug mode:
[image]

Worked second time after gap of nearly 12 hours
[image]

The AsyncImage does not display the image even though it is fetched

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72581627/cant-find-weatherkit-historical-data-and-trouble-with-attribution/72931810#72931810

Comment: When I implement the code as-is from the link you gave. It displays placeholder and then overwrites with image. The image seems to be empty. Please see edits I made to the original posting

Comment: Attribution URL shows up properly, whereas image does not come up.

Comment: Look at the link it has all you need, You can't show an image in the task. You should try some basic tutorials. I get the impression you are just copying and pasting from the internet without understanding what is going on.

Comment: No that is wrong assumption. I don't know everything, I do consult stackoverflow which has helped me a lot. I implemented the code in the link as-is and the Async image is displayed inside the VStack (not in the task)

Comment: same code tried after gap of few hours and it worked.

Comment: However the returned image still does not display in the view

Comment: The `AsyncImage` is inside the `task` in the code that you have shown.

Comment: I did not edit my original post, just tried the code in the link you provided, where task fetches the attribution and display is done inside the view. Edited now.